# How to display “allow dialogs from … to take you to their tab” in an alert?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, alert

I was in a website where an error message appeared in an [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) dozens of times, saying only:

> error :(

I’m used to websites automatically displaying a checkbox labeled “prevent this page from creating additional dialogs” after many error messages. This should have happened to the above site, but it didn’t. Instead it displayed a checkbox “allow dialogs from [example.com] to take you to their tab?”

Do you know why this happened? How do I reproduce this behavior in my own website?

PS: My browser is Firefox 72.0.2.

EDIT

4 months... Nobody have ever seen such a message?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini No, I don't have any. Actually I'm just curious about a behavior I've never seen before.

Answer (score 0):

This shows up in Firefox when a page that is not in view (some browser tab that is not activated) tries to display an `alert()` dialog. You might get this when some code that runs in background creates an alert message: like when you press a button, and some code runs in the background and you switch to another tab, and now the old tab finishes running and displays alert dialog.